# Value of type 'String' has no member 'uid'

Tags: firebase, swift4

In the following code, value of type 'String' has no member 'uid'

```
var userID: String!

if let email = emailField.text, let password = passwordField.text {
    Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: password) { (authData, error)

        in
        if error != nil {
            //create account
        } else {
            if let userID = userID?.uid {
                KeychainWrapper.standard.set((userID)!, forKey: ("uid"))
                self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "toFeed", sender: nil)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Of course the error is right. A `String` doesn't have an `uid` member. Where does `uid` come from? Maybe you mean `if let userID = user?.uid`

Comment: if you are using firebase Auth, I think you are referring to the `uid` field from `authData`, see the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/start#sign_in_existing_users)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking to do this:

```
if let userID = authData?.user.uid {
```

Comment: Thanks Frank once again!